# NSURLCache not saving properly

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsurlcache

I have some issues with NSUrlCache. I am using AFNetworking for my networkconnections. In the AppDelegate I declared

```
AFURLCache *sharedCache = [[AFURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:2 * 1024 * 1024
                                                        diskCapacity:100 * 1024 * 1024
                                                            diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

for caching.

I subclassed NSURLCache as followed

```
    - (NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    NSString *pathString = [[request URL] absoluteString];

    NSCachedURLResponse * response = [super cachedResponseForRequest:request];
    if (response != nil){
        return response;
    }

    return nil;
}

- (void)storeCachedResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse forRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    [super storeCachedResponse:cachedResponse forRequest:request];

    NSLog(@"STORE CACHED RESPONSE WITH URL %@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);
    NSLog(@"cache %@", [self cachedResponseForRequest:request]);

}
```

For some reason cachedResponseForRequest: is returning nil for all cached request on a deeper navigation level. Request from the rootviewcontroller are all cached properly. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: I think AFURLCache need to have proper http headers, did you check that? Check the function expirationDateFromHeaders at https://github.com/gimenete/iOS-boilerplate/blob/master/IOSBoilerplate/AFURLCache.m (line 191)